# Deleted default Compute Engine service account prevents creation of GKE Autopilot Cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-iam

For some reason it seems my project no longer has a default Compute Engine service account. I might of deleted some time ago and forgotten.

That's fine, as I usually assign specific service accounts when needed and rarely depend on the default one.

However, I am now trying to create an Autopilot GKE cluster, and I continue to get the annoying error:

> Service account "1673******-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" does not exist.

In the advanced options there is no possibility to select another service account.

I have seen other answers on StackOverflow regarding recreating the default account. I have tried those answers, as well as attempting to undelete. So far I have not had success with any.

How can I do one of the following:

1. Create a new default Compute Engine service account
2. Tell GKE which service account to use when creating an Autopilot cluster

Comment: If within 30 days try to [undelete](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/undelete)

Comment: To get that ID: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#finding-numeric-id

Comment: Hi @danyL, thanks, but my account was deleted more than 30 days ago  :/

Comment: You might need to create a new project or that is not an option right now?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that would be the only other option, it's really annoying, but I guess I will do it if no one can come up with a solution :)

Comment: gcloud beta container --project "xxxxx" clusters create-auto .......  then add the flags

Comment: I was looking for this [one](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create-auto)

Comment: Yeah I am able to create a standard cluster, that's no problem. I am specifically wanting to create an Autopilot one...

Comment: Ive put an answer below for autopilot, "create-auto" is autopilot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your cluster you just need to add this flag to specify your own SA

--service-account=XXXXXXXX

eg

> gcloud beta container --project "xxxxxx" clusters create-auto
> "autopilot-cluster-1" --region "us-central1" --release-channel
> "regular" --network "projects/xxxxxxx/global/networks/default"
> --subnetwork "projects/xxxxxx/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default" --cluster-ipv4-cidr "/17" --services-ipv4-cidr "/22" --service-account=xxxxxxxxxxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: will it also work for updating a running cluster?
I mean, run:
`gcloud beta container --project "xx" clusters update "cluster-name" --service-account=xxxxxx.iam.gserviceacount.com`

Comment: My suspicion no, On Compute engine, you have to stop instance, make the change. On standard GKE, you have to create a new node pool then migrate workloads. You cannot just change a SA or even stop and instance to make that change. I suspect it is the same on autopilot. You can also easily create a quick test and update with a new SA as a test.